# How to: Include friends with @ mentions in posts

Tags: android, android-edittext, tags

I have write "@" in edittext than open the friends listview and click on list item than add like tag with extra text,comments etc.

Kindly find attached screenshot.
Please give me any suggestion and any best android best library.

I have find ABCAutoCompleteTextView library in iOS but not any one in android like that library.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the ContactsProvider provided by the system. Query it with `CursorLoader`. There are lots of examples on the web how to do it.